# Creating Quantile classes when reclassifying raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, reclassify

I have a raster with a wide range of float values, and I'd like to reclassify it based on pixel distribution (Class 1 being bottom 25% of pixels, Class 4 being top 25% of pixels, etc).

I've been using the r.reclass (Grass) tool within the processing toolbox, and it allows for a 'reclass' text file to specify ranges. However, I'd like to automate this process within a model, so making a custom text file for each map isn't plausible.

Are there any other options for reclassifying based on pixel ranges?

---

So far, it seems that r.quant does not work, and r.quantile only outputs an html file, and not a usable txt file. r.recode may be an alternative to r.reclass, but it hasn't been working with the output from r.quantile. Still no solution.

Comment: do you mean you want to find quantiles/quartiles instead, rather than equal interval?

Comment: Honestly, I'd like to be able to do either or. It seems the only method for preparing the 'reclass.text' file is using hard numbers (ie. 10 thru 100 = 1), and not percentages (ie. 0% thru 10% = 1, 10% thru 70% = 2, etc). I haven't been able to find any documentation on flexible syntax for that document, so maybe there is a better QGIS reclassification method out there?

Comment: type in 'quant' into processing search, under models do you see Models > Example > Quantiles? I seem to have a model already but not sure if it comes with QGIS or is something I wrote a while back and forgotten about... couldn't find it in the qgis repos.

Comment: @StevenKay I do have an r.quant, which seems like it should do the trick. Thank you!!

Comment: yeah, I just saw that too! if you can get it to work, please do answer your own question, would love to know how to do this. (I'm sure I've done this analysis before, but I may have used my own code). My model seems to no longer work, it seems to want to run grass 6 which I no longer have installed :/

Comment: hmm, r.quant seems to not recognize any of my rasters for the 'layer to be quantized'. r.quantiles can generate an html file with the rules based on the number of classes chosen, but the format of the html file isn't compatible with the r.reclass tool. Back to the drawing board for now.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this using GDAL/Scipy/Numpy, but it has to be run outside of the QGIS environment. If anyone is reading this and would like the code logic to implement in a QGIS plugin or processing script, please shoot me a message

Comment: @StevenKay answered the question

Comment: Do you use by chance the old GRASS GIS 6 version? In GRASS GIS 7, there are two commands for that, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/keywords.html#quantile

Comment: @markusN see above comments- those tools weren't working for the intended purpose. All I could get from the r.quantiles was an html file that couldn't be used further in the Modeler, so I elected to just use GDAL and Scipy to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Alternatively, feel free to open an enhancement request at https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/

Comment: Will do, cheers!